# Can I put animation fade in with duration between button state enable and disable in jetpack compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-compose-button, android-jetpack-compose-button

This is how i create my button in compose

```
 Button(
        modifier = modifier,
        enabled = enabled.value,
        onClick = {}
    ) {
        Text(text = text)
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The background color of the `Button` is based on the colors defined in the `ButtonDefaults.buttonColors()`.

A workaround is to define the same color to `disabledBackgroundColor` and `backgroundColor`.
Something like:

```
var isButtonEnabled by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }
val animateStateButtonColor = animateColorAsState(
    targetValue = if (isButtonEnabled) Color.Blue else Teal200,
    animationSpec = tween(2000, 0, LinearEasing)
) 

Button(
    colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
        backgroundColor = animateStateButtonColor.value,
        disabledBackgroundColor = animateStateButtonColor.value,
    ),
    enabled = isButtonEnabled,
    onClick = { /* ... */ }
) {
    Text(text = "Button")
}
```

Comment: is there any way to give animation while declaring var isButtonEnabled?